# Writing JSON response values from Jmeter to a csv file into separate columns

Tags: json, jmeter

I need to export the JSON response values in jmeter to a CSV file. The Json response looks somewhat like the sample below. What would be the simplest approach to do this in Jmeter?

{
    "messages": null,
    "results": {
        "aaa": [
            {
                "code": "123",
                "name": "abc",
                "primary": true
            },
            {
                "code": "456",
                "name": "def",
                "primary": false
            }
        ],
        "bbb": null,
        "ccc": [
            {
                "code": "789",
                "name": "ghi",
                "primary": false
            },
            {
                "code": "222",
                "name": "jkl",
                "primary": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "errors": null
}

I want the output csv to look something like this:

result, code, name (headers)

aaa,    123,   abc

aaa,    456,   def

ccc,    789,   ghi

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how many variable are there in your JSON but you can try on this website:

http://convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm

Usually i do online but putting my JSON format from browser to this link above and get extracted to .CSV
See if that helps, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response, actually I am looking to perform this from Jmeter tool